# Custom font not taking effect using Webpack, Sass

Tags: css, webpack, custom-font

I am using `Webpack` to bundle my Sass files then process them into CSS. I also have custom fonts that I include in my Sass file via the `@font-face` mixin.

I have a folder structure as follows:

```
MyAppFolder
├── app
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── _custom_font.scss
│   │   ├── _variables.scss
│   │   └── main.scss
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── MyFont.otf
│   ├── images
│   │   └── home.png
│   ├── index.html
│   └── js
└── webpack.config.js
```

The `webpack.config.js` is as follows

```
^^^^ other config

loaders: [
  // SASS
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
  },

  // FONTS
  {
    test: /\.(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff)/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
  }
]
....
```

`_custom_font.scss` is as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src:  url('../fonts/MyFont.otf') format('otf');
}
```

`main.scss` is as follows:

```
body {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
}
```

Webpack goes away and builds everything fine. I can see its included the custom font file as in the webpack output I see the font file as an output file.

When viewing my web page I don't see the custom font applied. I see the css definition is correct but the font looks almost like Times New Roman. When I remove the definition from my Sass file it falls back to using **Helvetica Neue**. I have bootstrap so this is what I would expect.

Comment: If your compiled output is correct and what you expected, then this has nothing to do with Sass.  This looks like a typographical error to me (hint: there is no `@body`).

Comment: Ahh that was a mistake with the question. The actual scss definition is on **body** not **@body**. I can see the css definition in Chrome Dev Tools and its valid. The issue here is its valid but showing an incorrect font. Also I wasn't implying it was an issue with Sass but I was describing my entire build process as that may be applicable to a solution.

Comment: But your problem doesn't require someone with expertise in Sass to solve.

Comment: I have removed the Sass tag. I suppose the reason someone asks a question is because they are unsure of whats causing the issue. I explained my issue in full - it may have been relevant it may not have been.

Comment: Is the path to the fonts correct?

Comment: This is where I have some confusion. Take a look at my folder structure and font-family definition. If you were to compile that Sass using the command line it would simply reference the font using the relative path. With Webpack in the resultant css file I see a base 64 encoded string as the source. It's my understanding that this *is* the source of the font so I shouldn't have to worry about the path.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you have already found the answer somewhere. Anyway posting the answer for whoever is stuck here.

Resolve-url-loader helps. See https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader

Change your SCSS loader configs as below.

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
}
```

Make sure the `output.publicPath` is correctly configured. In most cases, it should be `/`.

```
output: {
  publicPath: '/'
}
```